# Counting word occurrences in Wikipedia

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Is there any way to use Wikipedia API to count the number of word occurrences in Wikipedia. For example, how many times the word "Hello" appears in Wikipedia? I read the MediaWiki API docs but could not find it there! appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe, what language will be using, what have you tried?

Comment: English language. I have tried using Wikipedia dump, but it takes time to give me the result. Therefore, I thought there might be a Wikipedia API that can do it faster.

Comment: @MaryLee: He's asking for your programming language :-) Using SQL on the dump is probably lots of faster than the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get a global word count from the API in a single call.  If you are interested in wordcounts, then your best bet would be using the database dumps: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html